# Access data from another view inside anothers view setOnCheckedListener

Tags: android, android-listview, simplecursoradapter, android-viewholder

I have a problem with my customadapter that extends simplecursoradapter. The problem is that inside a Listener for a view i want to acess data from another view. I could probaly use a checkedtextview but i dont think its looks good.

```
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_of_ingredients, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        holder.box = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.box);

        convertView.setTag(holder);



    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
```

Here is the tricky part inside setOnCheckedListener i would like to access the text in the textview my holder.name but i dont know how should make it work.

```
    holder.box.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            //array to store check / not checked
            checkBoxState.set(position, isChecked);

        }
    });
```

here is the rest of the code probaly not needed but i add it anyway.

```
        cursor.moveToPosition(position);
    holder.name.setText(cursor.getString(cursor
            .getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_NAME)));
    holder.box.setChecked(checkBoxState.get(position));

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: have you tried adapter.getView(position, null, listview) this will return the view and along with it its properties

Answer (score 0):

So i suppose you want to access your holder.name in your setoncheckedchangelistener
Create a class that extend that listener that look like this:

```
    private class OnCheckedChangedListener implements OnCheckedChangeListener{

private ViewHolder mViewHolder;

    public OnCheckedChangedListener(ViewHolder viewHolder){
        this.mViewHolder = viewHolder;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
            boolean isChecked) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final String name = this.mViewHolder.name.getText.toString();
    }

}
```

and use it in your checkbox like this:

```
viewHolder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangedListener(new OnCheckedChangedListener(viewHolder));
```